# retrieveing files

Tags: files, delete

Is it possible to retrieve files that I prevoiusly shift+delete ed ? Instead of shift+C I pressed shift + delete (I know they're not even close on the keyboard :S). I know on windows it is possibly using some software, but is it possible on ubuntu 10.04 also?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use extundelete. It is a utility to recover deleted files.
You can install it via the Ubuntu software center.